# Pending promise in aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, promise, jszip

I'm using the library [JSZip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ogr2ogr) to unzip a file and I am able to get each of the file name. However, what I want to do is to take the content of the file to do some processing. I know that you are able to do this by doing `zip.file(name).async(type).then()` according to the API.

For some reason though, when I do that in my lambda function, it doesn't hit that function at all. I tried to do return that line of code, but I just got `Promise <pending>`... I tried to wrap it with a try/catch and that didn't do anything. I did an async/await but that didn't work either. A callback like:

```
zip.file(name).async('blob').then(function(content) {
    //Do processing in here
});
```

doesnt seem to work either. What do I need to do to get the content of the specific file? Nothing I have done is work and I think it has to do with the promise pending. I'm stuck at this point and have no idea what to do.. Any help is greatly appreciated. For reference here is my code for how I'm doing it:

```
let zip = new JSZip();

zip.loadAsync(file).then(function(contents) {
    Object.keys(contents.files).forEach(function(name) {
        zip.file(name).async('blob').then(function(content) {
            // Processing here
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Full code:

index.js

```
const manager = require("./manager.js");

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {     
    return manager.manager(event, callback);
};
```

manager.js

```
exports.manager = async function (event, callback) {
    const path = '/temp/' + fileName;
    const file = fs.readFileSync(path);

    let zip = new JSZip();
    
    zip.loadAsync(file).then(function(contents) {
        Object.keys(contents.files).forEach(function(name) {
            zip.file(name).async('blob').then(function(content) {
                // Processing here
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What do the CloudWatch Logs show you? Did the Lambda function timeout or complete normally? What does your Lambda function return? You haven't included key parts of your code (like your console logs for debugging, your Lambda's function declaration, your Lambda's return statement).

Comment: The lambda function completes as normal. There isn't anything that is returned from the lambda except the console logs that I have included. I will update my question to provide the full code

Comment: In your Lambda handler declaration, don't use both async and callback. Use one or the other (preferably async). Also, for async handlers, you return a response, error, or promise to the Lambda runtime. Don't return nothing.

Comment: In an `async` function you should use the `await` keyword too.

Comment: What do you expect your `manager` to return?

Answer (score 0):

Change to have a return for the function:
`return zip.loadAsync(file).then(...)`